# Change waypoint icon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to modify the size of marker icon used to show gpx waypoints.
I know I should modify  `iconSize: [x,z]` and `iconAnchor: [y,z]`
but I don't find where (in which Leaflet file) it has to be modified.
I have even replaced `leaflet/images/marker-icon.png` with another PNG. It has no effect!

How can I do this?

I have no code to show because my question is  WHERE (in which script) the icon size is to be modified?

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Street Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="OpenStreetMap.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheet.css" >

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return (results === null)? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '10 10',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    customLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
}


var Marker = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'Point.png',

iconSize:     [27, 32], // size of the icon
iconAnchor:   [13, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
popupAnchor:  [0, -30] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var Lon = getUrlParameter('Lon')
var Lat = getUrlParameter('Lat')
var starts = new L.LayerGroup();

// ****************** change colors sequentially  *****************

var colors = [
'#3388ff',
'#800000',
'#9a6324',
'#808000',
'#469990',
'#000075',
'#000000', 
'#e6194b',
'#f58231',
'#ffe119',
'#bfef45',
'#3cb44b',
'#42d4f4',
'#4363d8',
'#911eb4',
'#f032e6',
'#a9a9a9',
//'#fabed4',    Pink
//'#ffd8b1',    Apricot
//'#fffac8',    Beige
//'#aaffc3',    Mint
'#dcbeff',
//'#ffffff' White
];

var n = 0;
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (!feature.properties.id) {
      feature.properties.id = n++;
    }
    var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
    return { color: colors[iColor] };
  }, 
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties.desc) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
  }
  layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight
  });
}



});

        var map = new L.LayerGroup();
        var runLayer = omnivore.gpx("../"+getUrlParameter('map'), null, customLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(map);


            var osmLink = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        ;
         var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors'
            ;
        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamFudXMwMDciLCJhIjoiY2l0azNvNjZlMDAzbTQ2bGk0dDFtaGhzcCJ9.8GAQYGpMFog62mRv17pGtA';

        var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
            satellite  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.satellite',   attribution: mbAttr});           
            
         var Stamen_Terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
            attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: 'abcd',
            ext: 'png'
        });     
        var standard = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
            maxZoom: 18
        });

        var map = L.map('map', {
            layers: [osmMap, starts, map],
        })
        .setView([49.21, 4.2], 8);

        var baseLayers = {  
            "OpenStreetMap": osmMap,                
            "OpenTopoMap": standard,
            "3D map" : Stamen_Terrain,
            "satellite": satellite,
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

        var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({
        position:  'bottomright',   
        fill: 'hollow',
        }).addTo(map);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: You say _"I have no code"_, but also _"I'm trying to modify the size of marker icon used to show gpx waypoints"_, which means you have some code. Icon size is to be modified in your own script.

Comment: I've added my html code, I don't see any marker icon in it.
The code I've tried to modify is the leaflet one, I've changed every occurrences of icon size and even deleted the icon.png, it has no effect.
So I'm wandering where the marker icon comes from and where I can modify its size.

Comment: It's hard to understand what are you trying to do with your code. You have group layer assigned to the variable `map`: `var map = new L.LayerGroup()`, but than you use the same variable name when defining map and then adding `map` as a layer to the map: `var map = L.map('map', {layers: [osmMap, starts, map]})`.

Comment: As far as your question is concerned, now that you published your code, it's clear what you want to do: change markers displayed as a part of GeoJSON layer. You'll get your answer when question is reopened. At the moment it needs two more reopen votes. Hint: see official Leaflet GeoJSON example: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/.

Comment: I'm far to be a js specialist !
It's the code I use to display gpx tracks, you helped me to display each track in a different color, it works fine, exemple https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map.html?map=VTT/Itineraires/LastYear.xml.
If I use the same code to display a .gpx file containning only waypoints it works fine too, example https://www.leforumrecifal.com/OSM/Map.html?map=OSM/LFRmembers.xml except the marker icons are too big, I just want to have smaller icons.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the use of the `map` variable. You need not be JS specialist, but you should now for each statement in your code why it's there and what it does, otherwise you'll be in trouble all the time.

Comment: I've found the solution overriding L.Icon.Default.prototype.options. properties (iconSize, iconAnchor, ...).
I would have like to override the defaut icon itself but if I set L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconUrl = 'Point.png' which is in the same folder as the html I get a boken image image (.png is not found) : how to ?

Comment: Good. If/when question is reopened, I'll publish another, more flexible solution.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the location of the .png file.

Comment: Your question was not about the location of .png file, but _"WHERE (in which script) the icon size is to be modified"_. That I'm intending to answer if/when question is reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your own marker/icon to be used for points in GeoJSON layer via `pointToLayer` option (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson), which is intended just for that purpose.

In you case the code to use marker with your icon `marker` would be:

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  pointToLayer: function(point, latlng) {
    var myMarker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: Marker
    });
    return(myMarker);
  },
  style: function(feature) {
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: I followed your code whith this but I get a syntax error unexpected token ')' : 
'code' style: function(feature) {  iconUrl = 'Point.png',
  iconSize = [15, 25],
  shadowSize = [25, 25],
  shadowAnchor = [7, 25]
  });
}

Comment: I didn't include all the code, just option `pointToLayer` that's new, the rest should be as in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I must add your code, not insert. Now except my variable is Marker not marker it works, thanks.